# Fatal error: Call to undefined method contains() in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, orm

I have a problem of recognition constrains() method in Symfony2. I have a relationship between the groups & Roles entities: So a group must have a mandatory role and the role may or may not have one or more groups. So in my addRoles function ( Groups $grp) I have checked each time if the group has a role so we joust if not assigning a role. But when inserting,

I encounter a problem:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   MemberShipManagement\GroupsBundle\Entity\Roles::contains() in
>   /var/www/Project_Console/src/MemberShipManagement/GroupsBundle/Entity/Roles.php
>   on line 118,

Class Groups:

```
   /**
     * @var Roles $role
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Roles", inversedBy="groups")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     *
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $role;
```

Class Roles:

```
/**
* @var ArrayCollection $groups
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Groups", mappedBy="role", cascade={"remove"} )
 *@Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $groups;

/**
 * Add group
 * @param Groups $grp
 */
public function addRoles(Groups $grp) {
  //  $grp->setRole($this);
    if (!$this->groups->contains($grp)) {   
        $this->groups->add($grp);
    }
    return $this;
          }
   /**
     * Remove groups
     * @param Groups $groups
     */
    public function removeRoles(Groups $groups)
    {
       if ($this->groups->contains($groups)) {
            $this->groups->removeElement($groups);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function __construct()
{
    $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to check if the data exists before calling the contains method like,

```
public function addRoles(Groups $grp) {
    //  $grp->setRole($this);
    if ( !isEmpty($this->groups) ){
        if (!$this->groups->contains($grp)) {   
            $this->groups->add($grp);
        }
    }
    return $this;
 }
```

since the error you get seems to be derived from the fact that $groups are not interpreted as ArrayCollection defined in doctrine.(if so, you could've called contains method defined there)

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

As long as other examples using contains method are found like this(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/i6IhBPHALkk) your approach looks correct.

Otherwise you could try to change $role to private instead of protected?